# i am trying to use template literals to display text from javascript in html but the elements are undefined, what do i do?

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

i am trying to display the name and selected shape elements in the outerText div in html, but they keep showing up as undefined.

```
here is the Javascript


let ShapeLink = (function(){
//code here!

return {
    initForm: function(frm){
        //code here!
        frm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
          document.getElementById('name').name,
          document.getElementById('shapeSelect').option;
        })
      let display = document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = 
  `${this.name} wants to see a ${this.shapeSelect}`;
      console.log(display);
      display.innerHTML =`
        <div id="outputText">
        ${this.name} wants to see a ${this.shapeSelect}
        </div>`

    }
}
})()
```

and here is the html

```
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
    <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
        <option value="">pick a shape</option>
        <option value="square">Square</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
<script>
    ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
</script>
</body>
```

note that i need to add all code into the Javascript file

Comment: Did you miss some characters when copying and pasting?

Comment: yep, just updated

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? Have you used your browser's script debugger?

Comment: Why is `ShapeLink` defined at all? You only need a single function to be called after `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: it is for what i am doing next. and i am not getting an error message per say it just shows as undefined, and running the function does not change it.

Comment: i want the display to show that ____ wants to see a (either square or circle)

Comment: @J.Morris, see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `this` inside the template literals with a variable value.Here `this` will point to the `form`.Also `document.getElementById('name').name,` will give the name but you may need the value of the input & `document.getElementById('shapeSelect').option;` need to be replaced by the 
`document.getElementById('shapeSelect').value;`

The form have a submit button, so on click of it it will try to submit the form. The default behaviour of the form can be prevented using the `event.preventDefault`

```js
let ShapeLink = (function() {
  var _name;
  var _selOption;
  return {
    initForm: function(frm) {
      frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the value attribute
        _name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        _selOption = document.getElementById('shapeSelect').value;
        //check if name and selected option is not undefined
        if (_name && _selOption) {
          document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = `${_name} wants to see a ${_selOption}`;
        }

      })
    }
  }
}())
ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
```

```css
ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
  <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
    <option value="">pick a shape</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="circle">Circle</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
```

Comment: There is no need to do additional queries to the DOM here, you already have access to the form object, see my answer.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen but why you downvoted.There may be multiple ways but no way my answer is wrong

Comment: I am not sure what this offers that isn't in my answer, besides a less optimal solution.

Comment: I agree that is how Stack Overflow should be, so I have removed my downvote. I don't feel that is the way Stack Overflow actually is in my experience, but maybe we can change it together.

Comment: Querying the DOM is slow. You query the DOM 4x, versus 2x in my solution. I don't need a benchmark to know that it is slower, and just a bad practice. `DOMContentLoaded` should _always_ wrap code that is going to query the DOM, you are asking for trouble by not doing it.

Comment: both your answers worked. i wroted the code with a little difference but they both worked.

Comment: @J.Morris, this answer will work but will not be as performant. That may not matter for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep all your JavaScript together, and there is no need to make your main function global. Beyond that, relying on `this` can get you into a world of hurt. Since you already have access to the form via `frm`, you may as well just access its `elements` property to get the values from your form:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const ShapeLink = {
    initForm: function(frm) {
      frm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        let display = document.getElementById('outputText');

        display.innerHTML = `
          <div id="outputText">
            ${frm.elements.name.value} wants to see a ${frm.elements.shapeSelect.value}
          </div>
        `;
      });
    },
  };

  ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector('form'));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
  <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
    <option value="">pick a shape</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="circle">Circle</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
```